# Using IBM Swift Sandbox and rangeOfCharacterFromSet

Tags: swift, nsstring, ibm-swift-sandbox

I am trying swift on IBM's new Swift online Sandbox.
The following script is not running on that sandbox: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/

```
import Foundation


func palindromTest(s: String) -> Bool{
    let lower = s.lowercaseString
    let letters = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()
    let onlyLetters = lower.characters.filter({String($0).rangeOfCharacterFromSet(letters) != nil})
    let reverseLetters = Array(onlyLetters).reverse()

    return String(onlyLetters) == String(reverseLetters)
}

palindromTest("abc")
```

The sandbox prints the following error message:

```
/swift-execution/code-tmp.swift:7:48: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'rangeOfCharacterFromSet'
    let onlyLetters = lower.characters.filter({String($0).rangeOfCharacterFromSet(letters) != nil})
```

Did I forget to import something? Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rangeOfCharacterFromSet` is one of the many `String` methods 
which are actually handled by `NSString`.

From [this commit](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/commit/6c1cab39f20e2c21b040e31aabef1a15c69ce095)
to NSString.swift, it seems that support for `rangeOfCharacterFromSet`
was added only recently to the (non-Apple)  Foundation library,
so you cannot use it until the IBM Swift Sandbox is updated to use
a new Swift version.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this works now in the Sandbox [swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/aae5d1caf4e0a6232ff428c3a0160e6e98cba6ed913ce9176f2baee46d30cb1c](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/aae5d1caf4e0a6232ff428c3a0160e6e98cba6ed913ce9176f2baee46d30cb1c)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things have changed since these answers were given. [I've updated Pat's Sandbox answer for Swift 3.1.1](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/592450ba75100825bbe55341). Below is the code and a summary of the API changes.

Several methods in the standard library and Foundation have since been renamed:

- Array: `.reverse()` → `.reversed()`
- String: `.rangeOfCharacterFromSet()` → `.rangeOfCharacter(from:)`
- (NS)CharacterSet: `.lettersCharacterSet()` → `.letters`

I also made a slight change, perhaps just from personal preference. Rather than use `String.rangeOfCharacter(from:)` I chose to use `CharacterSet.contains()`, which required I use `String.unicodeScalars` instead of `.characters`. Not sure about the performance tradeoffs in general, but I liked how cleaned things up.

```
import Foundation

func palindromTest(_ word: String) -> Bool{
    let letters = CharacterSet.letters
    let onlyLetters = word.lowercased().unicodeScalars.filter { 
        letters.contains($0)
    }.map { Character($0) }
    let reverseLetters = onlyLetters.reversed()
    print("\(String(onlyLetters)) == \(String(reverseLetters))")
    return String(onlyLetters) == String(reverseLetters)
}

print(palindromTest("abc")) 
// false

print(palindromTest("dud")) 
// true
```